# How to not perform destructive reads?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've got a function that saves the values of a query into a PHP array. I had code that looked like this:

```
if(mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        foreach($line as $row => $value){
            $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
            array_push($rows, $value);
        }
    }
    return $rows
}
```

I noticed it would not save the first row of values, and I debugged and found the root cause of this bug to be in the line `if(mysqli_fetch_row($result)){` ... Basically once it got to the while loop it was starting on the second row. To make sure I wasn't missing any data from the query, I changed the code to this:

```
$line = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if($line){
    //var_dump($line);
    foreach($line as $row => $value){
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
        array_push($rows, $value);
    }
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        //var_dump($line);
        foreach($line as $row => $value){
            $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
            array_push($rows, $value);
        }
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

There has to be an if statement, because there's an else clause to handle no data returned. I think I'm on the right path with the `$line = mysqli_fetch_row($result);` line before the `if` statement, but I feel like having two foreach loops is redundant, and probably unnecessary.

Comment: Calling `mysqli_fetch_row($result)` would bring the first row back which is why you aren't getting the first row returned in your loop. You could use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check whether you've returned any results and output error if not, then loop over the results if you have.

Comment: @scrowler I like your answer the most put it as an answer if you want the rep

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
if($line = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    while($line){
        foreach($line as $row => $value){
            $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
            array_push($rows, $value);
        }
        $line = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just count rows returned .. ?

```
while($line = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    foreach($line as $row => $value){
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
        array_push($rows, $value);
    }
}
if( !empty($rows) ){
    return $rows;
}
else{
    // what you do in your script if "if(mysqli_fetch_row($result))" returns false
}
```